# Access Azure Function App system keys in Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-eventgrid

I want to create Azure EventGrid subscription using Terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic_event_subscription" "function_app" {
  name                = "RunOnBlobUploaded"
  system_topic        = azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic.function_app.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  included_event_types = [
    "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
  ]

  subject_filter {
    subject_begins_with = "/blobServices/default/containers/input"
  }

  webhook_endpoint {
    url = "https://thumbnail-generator-function-app.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/blobs?functionName=Create-Thumbnail&code=<BLOB-EXTENSION-KEY>"
  }
}
```

By following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#deployment), I successfully deployed it and it works. However, the `webhook_endpoint` URL needs `<BLOB-EXTENSION-KEY>` which is hardcoded right now and found from the following place in the portal:

[image]

In order to not commit a secret to GitHub, I want to get this value by reference, ideally using Terraform.

According to my research, it seems there is no way in Terraform to reference that value.
The closest one is this data source `azurerm_function_app_host_keys` in Terraform. However, it doesn't cover the `blobs_extension` key!

Is there any good way to reference `blobs_extension` in Terraform without a hardcoded value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TF does not support it yet, you can create your own [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) which is going to use azure cli or sdk to get the value you want, and return it to your TF for further use.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a good last resort. I will try it.

Comment: @codigube How did it go? Did the external data source work?

Comment: Hi, I have writen the externa data source with scripts to call Azure API to fetch the system keys. However, it failed due to authentication. trying to figure out correct way to handle authentication against Azure in the bash script. The API works from the Console

Comment: yes. you are right. thanks! I have accepted your answer as the solution